# How to summarize aging data into age grouping in SAP WebI

Tags: webi

Using WebI 4.2, I am trying to summarize aging data for individual unit into Aging Group distribution for Material Number as shown below. I am getting either #MultiValue or weird numbers displayed. I'll need some help on how can I get the desired outcome.

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yadbz.png)

[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqjOb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is to create a variable called **Aging Category**...

```
=If([Aging (Days)] <= 10; "Aging (0 - 10 days)";
  If([Aging (Days)] <= 20; "Aging (11 - 20 days)";
  If([Aging (Days)] <= 30; "Aging (21 - 30 days)";
  If([Aging (Days)] <= 40; "Aging (31 - 40 days)";
  "Aging (> 40 days)"))))
```

You may or may not know that Web Intelligence allows two types of syntax for **If...Then...Else** statements. I prefer the one above, but this is equivalent...

```
=If [Aging (Days)] <= 10 Then
    "Aging (0 - 10 days)"
  ElseIf [Aging (Days)] <= 20 Then
    "Aging (11 - 20 days)"
  ElseIf [Aging (Days)] <= 30 Then
    "Aging (21 - 30 days)"
  ElseIf [Aging (Days)] <= 40 Then
    "Aging (31 - 40 days)"
  Else 
    "Aging (> 40 days)"
```

Put that in for the column header of your crosstab. Then create a varible to count your units...

```
=Count([Serial Number])
```

That goes in the body of the crosstab.

[image]

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Appreciate that.